# How to loop multiple condition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

Can i loop in 2 condition vb net?

```
Dim s As New DirectoryInfo("C:/ProgramFiles")
Dim files As FileInfo() = s.GetFiles("*.jpg")
For i As Integer = 1 To files.Count 'condition 1 get loop Number of Files
    For Each f As FileInfo In files 'condition 2 get loop Files
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(f.FullName)
    If bmp.Width >= 1000 Then
        Console.WriteLine(i & ". True--> Name : " & f.FullName & " Width: " & bmp.Width.ToString() + " > Height: " & bmp.Height.ToString())
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(i & ". False--> Name : " & f.FullName & " Width: " & bmp.Width.ToString() + " > Height: " & bmp.Height.ToString())
    End If
    Next
Next
Console.Read()
```

How to get number in each result?

Example number: 1, 2, 3, ...

```
1. True--> Name : a.jpg Width:1000 > Height:500
2. False--> Name : b.jpg Width:800 > Height:400
3. True--> Name : c.jpg Width:1200 > Height:600
4...
```

but the code result is:

```
1. True--> Name : a.jpg Width:1000 > Height:500
1. False--> Name : b.jpg Width:800 > Height:400
1. True--> Name : c.jpg Width:1200 > Height:600
2. True--> Name : a.jpg Width:1000 > Height:500
2. False--> Name : b.jpg Width:800 > Height:400
2. True--> Name : c.jpg Width:1200 > Height:600 
3...
```

I'm very beginner coding in vb.net

Thanks for your advice,.

Comment: I think you don't need your outer loop. Just remove the `For i As Integer = 1 To files.Count.. ` and see if you get the expected results

Comment: @Pikoh what about the numbers in each result? `1, 2, 3...`

Comment: Just define a count variable outside the `For Each`  and increment it in the loop

Comment: @Pikoh can you give me an example? I don't understand what you explained :( how to increment count in the `For Each`??

Comment: see my answer, and have a look at `count`variable, and how it is incremented at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the outer loop, you don't need it. In order to ouput an index, just use a variable and increment it in the loop:

```
Dim s As New DirectoryInfo("C:/ProgramFiles")
Dim files As FileInfo() = s.GetFiles("*.jpg")
Dim count As Integer = 1
For Each f As FileInfo In files 
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(f.FullName)
    If bmp.Width >= 1000 Then
         Console.WriteLine(count & ". True--> Name : " & f.FullName & " Width: " & bmp.Width.ToString() + " > Height: " & bmp.Height.ToString())
   Else
        Console.WriteLine(count & ". False--> Name : " & f.FullName & " Width: " & bmp.Width.ToString() + " > Height: " & bmp.Height.ToString())
   End If
   count += 1
Next

Console.Read()
```

Comment: I am very grateful, it's very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

/* Simple*/

Dim Count As Integer = 1;
End of the I loop increase it with count++;

and replace i with this variable so you can get proper indexing

Comment: `Count++ & ". True--> Name : " & f.Name & ...`

`Error1 : Expression expected.`

i get error while replace i with count++, how to increase count in the loop?

Comment: count += 1 @saya you can increase like this